# shared printer job authentication syntax

Tags: 16.04, printing, sharing

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I mapped on it a printer shared from a Windows PC but each time that I try printing a test page or launching just any print job, it is requiring authentication (I assume it wants the credentials from my user on my Windows PC) but when I enter it exactly, it does nothing. since no error or refusal message of any kind is displayed at this point, I can only guess that it refused the authentication as it may need the domain name with it. I tried many combinations, with slashes placed where I think it needs them, to no avail. I need to know what is the specific username syntax I need to enter.